# ESP8266 baud rate not right after reset

Tags: arduino, esp8266

After getting my ESP to finally work. I was trying to make a GET request. But somehow it got stuck. So I tried to reset. But after that my ESP didn't want to respond to any of my commands. And the only way I get response from the ESP is by pressing the reset button on the ESP itself. The message I get from the ESP is:

```
sll⸮⸮s⸮c⸮o⸮⸮l⸮p⸮|⸮⸮⸮⸮p⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮p⸮8⸮o⸮loo⸮ccp⸮⸮cl`slp⸮o⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮lco⸮⸮oll⸮⸮c⸮|⸮o⸮l⸮⸮l`⸮ool`os⸮⸮⸮⸮㏏l`p⸮o⸮⸮⸮⸮os⸮lo⸮ls`⸮s⸮⸮o⸮pcoldon't use rtc mem data
sl⸮⸮o
```

This is the code I am using:

```cpp
SoftwareSerial esp8266(2, 3);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(115200);
}
```

Comment: It isn't recommended to run software serial at 115200.

Comment: I know it is not. But the last time I could go there and change the baudrate. The stuckgetting happened at 9600.

Comment: When the ESP8266 boots it dumps out some bootloader message at 74880 baud.